# How can batch multi charge from a different customer Stripe with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, batch-processing

I want to collect charge from group of customers and then make a transfer for connected account at the same time ,i search for something like Transaction or batch process in stripe but I don't find anything .this [image](https://www.sharewithdaisy.com/static/images/pages/home/home-block-2-demo-1.gif) explain what i want to make exactly

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
amount: 2000,
currency: 'eur',
payment_method_types: ['card'], },
  function(err, paymentIntent) {
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended flow for `n` charges would be to create `n` `PaymentIntents` via the Stripe API. You would create a `PaymentIntent` for each of the `Customers`, and you can use `metadata` to connect them in your own system (Stripe tracks the key-value `metadata` pairs, and you can use those to reconcile each `PaymentIntent` against your own tracking of groups of `Customers` in each payment).

For example, if you have two (2) `Customers` that are evenly splitting `amount: 2000` and the connected account's `id` is `acct_123abc`:

```
['cus_abc123', 'cus_xyz789'].forEach(customer_id => {
    stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 1000,
      currency: 'eur',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      customer: customer_id,
      transfer_data: {
        destination: 'acct_123abc'
      },
      metadata: {
        my_internal_id: 'internal_payment_id'
      }
    }).then(payment_intent => {
      console.log(payment_intent.id);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
});
```

You can use your own internal payment id in place of "internal_payment_id" from the `metadata` to tie each `PaymentIntent` to a payment in your own system.

Comment: What specific type of error are you looking to remediate? If it's an error with payment, I'd suggest using [Separate Auth and Capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) and then once all of the payments are authorized, only then would you capture them all at once.

Comment: make capture one by one ?

Comment: Once all the authorizations are successful, you'd capture each individually back-to-back, yes.